# How do you make an Express.js API accessible from the Internet?

Tags: api, express

I have an Express API server running on localhost on my own machine.  How do I make it accessible from the Internet and not just my own machine?

Preferably, it would be deployed on AWS.

Comment: you could use a service like `https://www.heroku.com` - they have free instances available to play around with - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#introduction

Comment: @evvels1 sorry, I forgot to mention that preferably, it would be deployed on AWS.  Is there any Heroku-like services on AWS?

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/getting-started-nodejs.html - you could prob get a free basic instance for a year, but if you're just messing around then you can just use `heroku` for that

Comment: I know how to set up nodejs on an Ec2 instance.  But when I run my server, it's only running on localhost...

Comment: there should be a public address for your instance i.e. `ec2-203-0-113-25.compute-1.amazonaws.com`.

Comment: also, make sure to set the security-group open for public on port 80, or whatever port you use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AWS there are multiple ways of hosting your express application based on flexibility vs convenience.

- AWS Elastic Beanstalk:
  This will provide you more  convenience by creating an autoscaling and loadbalancing environment with version management and roll back support from one place in AWS web console. Also provide you IDE support for deployments and CLI commands for  CI/CD support.
- AWS ECS:
  If you plans to dockerize your application(Which I highly recommend) you can use AWS ECS to manage your docker cluster with container level Autoscaling and loadbalancing support for more convenience. This also provides CLI for CI/CD.
- AWS EC2:
  If you need more flexibility, you can get a virtual server in AWS and also manually configure autoscaling and loadbalancing which I prefer as the least option simply for a web app since you have to do most of the things manually.

All this services will provide you with publicly accessible URL if you configure them properly to grant access from outside. You need to configure networking and security groups properly either exposing the loadbalancer or instance IP/DNS URL to the outside.